# Kubernetes Service and Ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I'm learning Kubernetes at the moment and just had a question I'd like to have clarified regarding exposing Services and making Pods accessible to the public internet.

Lets say I have an Java Spring boot application which has an embedded Tomcat server using JSP, MySQL Pod and Memcached (All on separate Pods), and I'd like to expose them as a Service making them publicly available.

I'm confused as to which type of Service each of these Pods would need , and also why. I'm aware that of Ingress and using a single Load Balancer to route requests from Services instead of multiple Load Balancers, but the actual Service type is what I'm finding hard to understand based on the what work the Pod needs to do.

Comment: To quote the kubernetes tag description, "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering which Service type do you need: it's always ClusterIP.

LoadBalancers and NodePort are reserved for very specific use cases. One requiring to be integrated with a cloud (provisioning loadbalancers), the other requiring your kubernetes nodes being exposed to external clients, allowing connections to non-default ports.

When you don't know or you're not sure: just assume you can't use NodePort or LoadBalancers. As a cluster end-user, developer or Kubernetes beginner: ClusterIP is the only Service type you need.

Exposing your application to clients outside of your SDN, you want to use Ingresses. As again, while LoadBalancers or NodePorts might be suitable technical solutions on paper, they usually aren't in practice -- and when they are, there are security aspect to consider: better dealt with by your cluster administrator.